# Replace multiple characters in string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace the following `This_is_awesome_news_ZZ__T` and the end result I'm looking to have is this: `This is awesome news`

Here is the javascript replace function:

```
var str = 'This_is_awesome_news_ZZ__T';
return str.replace(/_ZZ__T|_|/g,'');
```

the above function returns `Thisisawesomenews`

How can I have space between like this: `This is awesome news`

If I try space something like this `str.replace(/_ZZ__T|_|/g,' ')`
then it returns `T h i s  i s  a w e s o m e  n e w s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra pipe (alternation) at the end of your regex here that is causing the regex to match in between each character.

`str.replace(/_ZZ__T|_/g,' ');` should do what you're looking for (replace instances of `_ZZ__T` or `_` with a single whitespace). Note that the final `|` is not present here.

Sites like regex101.com or regexr.com (I have no affiliation with these sites) are useful for debugging regex. In particular, regexr emitted a warning about the expression possibly returning empty matches.

Comment: @NickKahn You should look through the functions available for the String type to see if there's anything that looks useful. Something like a "substring" function would do the job pretty easily.

Comment: yea figured out, I end-up using `trim()` at the end